# Connect to Oracle with PHP via ODBC

Tags: php, database, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I'll start off by saying I am thoroughly confused.  I've read through "The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual White Paper" and through some similar questions on StackOverflow and I still have no idea what I need to do.

I'm using PHP 5.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I'm trying to connect to Oracle 11g.  I don't know if I **need** Instant Client or Oracle XE.  I want to connect to it using PDO as that's how my code is already structured but I can't make heads or tails of the documentation.  I also have an option to connect via ODBC.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any way, you need at least instant client if you are connecting with PDO.

Oracle XE contains OCI runtime (Oracle call interface), but you may need to setup some environment variables to make it work.

Is it Oracle XE instance on same server as Apache/PHP ?

You have couple of good articles on google's search result like:

1. http://www.sitepoint.com/oracle-10g-xe-and-php/
2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_one.htm
3. http://web3us.com/drupal6/how-create-web-site-handbook/oracle-xe-php  [Recommended reading]
4. http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Configuring-Oracle-Database-XE-and-PHP/
5. http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php